# How can i use python coroutines as celery tasks

Tags: python, celery, tornado, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have old celery version in my tornado project. My current celery version is 3.1.23. There was an old library https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery which is dead now, so i would like to get rid of it and update celery to new version.

I don't want to change a tons of code, so i would like to have an ability to use async/await syntax in my celery tasks. Is it possible to do something like this

```
@app.task
async def add(x, y):
    res = await some_async_function(x)
    ......
```

?

I've seen only examples with synchronous code and i'm not sure if my case is suitable for celery

Any tip will be good for asyncio or tornado.

UPD:

Even though celery tasks are already asynchronous, i need ability to use coroutines. I need coroutines, because currently we have a lot of tasks written with asynchronous calls, it was possible thanks to the tornado-celery library and some kind of black magic. We have database calls via async driver, async calls to AWS and so on. And because of that i need a possibility to work with asyncronous syntax inside celery tasks. I can use something like event_loop.run_until_complete(...) in asyncio or tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(lambda: do_something(1)) in tornado for example, but it's definitely not preferable way

Answer (score 4):

At the moment that is not possible as far as I know...

Celery tasks are executed asynchronously anyway, so really no need to use coroutines. `delay()`, `apply_async()` and `send_task()` are returning the AsyncResult (future-like object). This all makes sense as Celery predates Python's asyncio and async/await that later came into the language.

If you absolutely must use async/await, the only solution I can think of is to wrap your async logic inside a regular Celery task.

Comment: Yes, they are asynchronous, however my issue is in different area. I need coroutines, because currently we have a lot of tasks written with asynchronous calls. For instance database calls via async driver, async calls to AWS and so on. I need a possibility to work with asyncronous syntax inside celery tasks. I can use something like `event_loop.run_until_complete(...)` in asyncio or `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(lambda: do_something(1))` in tornado for example, but it's definitely not preferable way

Answer (score 2):

This **is not** the most efficient solution but it is stable and idiot-proof.

I have created a simple decorator for running async functions in a sync way using `asyncio.run`.

```py
def async_to_sync(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.run(func(*args, **kwargs))

    return wrapped
```

How to use it?

1. Copy decorator somewhere
2. Create your async function
3. Add decorator
4. Do whatever you would do with regular sync function

[image]
[image]

Alternative if you don't want to use decorator:

```py
@app.task()
def that_one_task():
    async def body():
        ac = AsyncClient()
        print(await ac.get('https://httpbin.org/get'))
        await ac.aclose()
        
    return asyncio.run(body())
```